# Getting value into item array of DataTable

Tags: c#

I have a simple foreach of datatable as:

```
foreach(DataRow designKey in designFolioList.Rows)
{

}
```

So I have 2 items into each row like:

[image]

So I want to get value of the first one I try:

```
foreach(DataRow designKey in designFolioList.Rows)
{
    var currentDesignKey = designKey[0] as string;
}
```

But currentDesignKey is always null? What am I doing wrong? How is the correct way to get item 0 from table?

Comment: Since it’s not a string you’ll always get a null when using `as`. You probably want `.ToString()` if you want it as a string

Comment: The correct way of getting item 0 is `designKey[0]`. Why are you trying to convert it to a sting? It isn't a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by that screenshot, designKey[0] is not a string, it's an int. Because it is not directly castable to a string, using `as string` on it will result in a null. Think of `as` as a form of cast that doesn't crash if it doesn't work out. This doesn't work out:

```
object o = 123;
string s = (string)o;
```

It crashes like this:

> Run-time exception (line xx): Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.

`as` doesn't crash, it just returns null for casts that don't work;

If you really want it as a string, call `.ToString()` on it. Otherwise, cast it to an int(or long/whatever it is)

```
foreach(DataRow designKey in designFolioList.Rows)
{
    var currentDesignKey = (int)designKey[0];
    var currentDesignKeyStr = designKey[0].ToString();
}
```

`.ToString()` works because object has `.ToString()`, and so does `int` (by way of override). ToString()ing an int, turns it into a string representation of itself: `123 -> "123"`